# Playing Encrypted audiobook mp3 android and ios

Tags: encryption, mp3, drm

I am trying to develop a secure Android / iOS mobile player of audio books:
something like audible but for a smaller range of books and services!
i am wondering, instead of using the well known DRM solutions like Microsoft Playready etc…, i am thinking of using encrypted files and decrypting them in order to play in the embedded mobile player

i have found this [how to encrypt and decrypt audio file android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274768/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-audio-file-android), but i am not sure if this is the right solutions.
i would not like anyone to be able to take the decrypted file and use it.
In general i would like to protect my recorded mp3s by encrypting them and then when the user downloads the encrypted mp3 , play them by decrypting them in the player

Comment: You should try it yourself, then if you have problems, you create a question and **add your code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provides cryptography API's which support industry standard AES based encryption. This is likely to be good enough for your needs - if anyone figure out how to break AES they will likely have higher priority targets than music and video etc.

There is an introduction and overview here (in case the link breaks the key term to search for us 'apple CommonCrypto'):

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html

However, you still have the problem of getting your key securely from the server to the client. This is actually one of the main pieces of functionality that DRM systems provide.

If you are comfortable you can do this is some way that is secure enough for your needs, for example sending it to your users in a separate encrypted message, then you should be good to go. If not then, it may be easier to just leverage an existing DRM.