# React-Native: library to play audio from memory buffer

Tags: security, react-native, audio, memory, mobile

I'm looking for 2 things in the area of react-native audio handling.

1. I would like to play audio from some in-memory buffer (not file in the device, and not url streaming). is it possible and are there RN libs for doing it?

The reason for such request is necessity to store audio data secured in some offline db, not exactly in package. probably, with ability to download and save after app installation, but saving in secured way.

2. Do you know any best practices in storing audio locally in devices (keeping in mind that its React Native mobile app) in secure way? so to prevent ability to open package and extract audio from it? the reason - to defense copyright of audio files and let listen them only via application.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could read these guidelines before asking a new question. Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If it is possible with android, it's possible in react-native as well. You would have to write native modules which can interact with the react-native ones.

Comment: What are you referring to by `in-memory buffer` in android?

Comment: By in memory buffer, I mean situation, when I get audio as output from some function (like decryptor or similar), not just file in a device or url from server for streaming. no matter is it android or iOS

Comment: I am not quite clear about the data format of the output you are referring to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274768/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-audio-file-android might help.

Comment: thanks! actually, the idea itself, no matter with encryption or not, is in ability to play some audio without having it in some file on a device. Imagine the simple case, I've read some say base64 string from REST API, or from mobile data base, whatever, I decrypted it - as a result I have bytes of that audio. How Can I play it in React Native?