# How to encrypt and decrypt tensorflow model in android successfully

Tags: android, tensorflow, encryption, decompiler

As files in android assets can be easily hacked by converting .apk to .zip. I have some propitiatory model which I need to use in android application. I am working on how to encrypt the assets of the application. ( I will use firebase for retreiving  the key for decryption to make it more secure ) 
I am pretty successful in encrypting and decrypting images (png and jpg) using cipher library in android.

Following is the code which I used for the purpose.

```
    String fake = "sadhkja6";
    byte[] encodedKey     = Base64.decode(fake, Base64.DEFAULT);
    yourKey= new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500,500, true);

   byte[] output = getBytes(bitmap);

   byte[] output = getBytesFile();
   saveFile(output);


public static byte[] encodeFile(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length,
            algorithm);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(
            new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    encrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);
    return encrypted;
}


public byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap){

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(    Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    bitmap.recycle();

    return byteArray;
}

public static byte[] encodeFile(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length,
            algorithm);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(
            new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    encrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);
    return encrypted;
}

void saveFile(byte[] array) {
    String decrypted_file = "encypted.png";

    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator, decrypted_file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(file));
        yourKey = generateKey();
        byte[] filesBytes = encodeFile(yourKey, array);
        bos.write(filesBytes);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I use the same code for encyrpting tensorflow models, the model is not successfully decompiled resulting in app crash. Most probably because we are loading the model in bytes which may cause problems.

Please tell me how can I use the cyphering technique for securing my tensorflow model. Thank you very much.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274768/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-audio-file-android) one way.

Comment: Let me try if it works. Thanks

Comment: It did not work. Tensorflow interpreter can not take it as input. 
When I open model in netron it says "Invalid FlatBuffers signature '' in 'decyrpted.tflite;.